# Running a Post Build script when a Jenkins job is aborted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, post-build

Is there a possible way / plugin that can run a post build script when a Jenkins job is aborted.
I do see that the post build plugin provides an action to execute a set of scripts, but these can be run only on 2 options either a successful job or a failed job.

Answer (score 26):

This question is positively answered [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180816192905/http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Cleanup-after-job-abort-td4663242.html).

The [Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin is run even if a job is aborted.

Use it to search the log text for "Build was aborted" and you can specify a shell script to run.

Works like a charm. :-)

Comment: I will try. However the issue here is that the Jenkins status is Success, not Aborted

Comment: The linked answer does not exist anymore :/

Answer (score 6):

For a declarative Jenkins pipeline, you can achieve it as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES')   // abort on exceeding the timeout
    }

    stages {
        stage('Echo 1') {
           steps {
              echo 'Hello World'
          } 
        }
        stage('Sleep'){
            steps {
                sh 'sleep 180'
            }
        }
        stage('Wake up'){
            steps {
                echo "Woken up"
            }
        }
    }
    // this post part is executed if job is aborted
    post {
        aborted {
            script{
              echo "Damn it. I was aborted!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, instructions in the `always`, `unsuccessful` and `cleanup` conditions of the `post` step are run when a job is aborted (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if a build is aborted, there's no way to execute any build steps (or post build steps) in it any more - which makes sense, that's what I would expect of "abort".

What you could do is create another job that monitors the first one's status, and triggers if it was aborted (e.g. see the [BuildResultTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) plugin).

Another solution might be to create a "wrapper" job, which calls the first one as a build step - this way you can execute additional steps after its completion, like checking its status, even if it was aborted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a scripted pipeline, you can always use a try/catch/finally set, where the build gets executed in the try block and the postbuild steps are in the finally block. This way, even if the build fails, post build steps are executed.

```
try {
        build here
}catch(FlowInterruptedException interruptEx){

    catch exception here
} finally {

    postBuild(parameters)

}
```